# Get part of Vector in C++ like pointer to middle of C array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I'm new to C++ (although also a relative newbie to C) and I've written some code in which I read a file into a char Vector. I then need to consume chunks of this vector and pass the next chunk to an appropriate class for handling.

In C, I would have simply made a char array, and then moved a pointer along the chunks. Basically I could treat the pointer position as a "new" array for the sake of my processing classes and it's efficient since I don't need to copy the data at all.

for example:

```
char arr[100];
char *pa = &arr[0];
char *pa_half = &arr[50];
//pass pa somewhere and pa_half elsewhere for processing
```

I more or less want this behavior in C++. Do I need to initialize new Vectors each time? If so, does this mean I have to copy the data?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the same thing with `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> arr(100);
char *pa = &arr[0];
char *pa_half = &arr[50];
//pass pa somewhere and pa_half elsewhere for processing
```

Or if you use `iterator`:

```
std::vector<char> arr(100);
auto pa = arr.begin();
auto pa_half = pa + 50;
//pass pa somewhere and pa_half elsewhere for processing
```

Note that pointer or iterator will become invalid if [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) get destroyed or reconstructed.

Comment: Ahhh yes ok i was about to write up my discovery of iterators. Seem like the 'C++' way of doing this! thanks!

Comment: @flyingsilverfin Yes, iterator is "c++ way" more. You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You could use std::string to store the data read from file, which is intuitive to store char string data. Always remember any c++ STL data structure is suppose to resize and relocate the underlying data upon extending, and invalidates any prior pointer/iterator. So taking pointer/iterator of inside STL  data structure, modifying data structure and expecting the pointer/iterator to be valid is not correct.

So as long as you do not change the string content once you read it from file.
below code should work fine.

```
std::string arr;
arr.reserve(MAX_FILE_SIZE); // for efficient read to avoid frequent relocation.

.... read file in the std::string arr...

char *pa = arr.c_str() + 0;
char *pa_half = arr.c_str() + 50;

.... pa and pa_half are valid till you do not change string arr or relocation does not happen, if array is std::string or std::vector ... 

//pass pa somewhere and pa_half elsewhere for processing
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the correct approach, but I'm actually not using char's but uint8_t (which happens to be defined as char on my machine) to read a binary file. I figured binary file shouldn't really be stuffed into a string since I don't know how it's all handled internally

Comment: string will handle the binary data correctly. It will recognize the binary characters which you 'push_back' in the string even if you have pushed back '\0' in the middle of string. It will give you string.size() equal to size of file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the pointer itself. The `&vec.front()` will return the real pointer of the vector.